# Compile C++ with netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm currently making a small C++ program for my friends. I'm using Netbeans in school for Java and wanted to use Netbeans for C++ too (I want to use the same IDE for everything).

Now when I run my program in netbeans, it works perfectly in the IDE. But when I try to compile my program I can't seem to find the .exe file. I can only find the debug .exe file, which I can't run because I miss 3 .dll files (cygstdc++-6.dll, cygwin1.dll and cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll)

Am I doing something wrong? I can't seem to find the problem at this moment

thx for the help

Comment: compile in release mode. check https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have release `.exe` - you need to compile in `Release` mode instead of `Debug`

Regarding the issue with missing files:
My assumption is that `Netbeans` has a built-in compiler (which from your explanation appears to be one within [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) environment). Having it **built-in** simply means that the IDE knows a path to all the sources (`.dll`) and header files

When you try to run the `.exe` out of the IDE - your executable cannot find these libraries (`cygstdc++-6.dll`, `cygwin1.dll` and `cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll`) because they're *not set in the environment variables* and are not visible from the executable's folder. (I expect, that the path to these `.dll`s is not hardcoded)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the Release mode, btw how can I add set the .dll's in enviroment variables? Is this via netbeans or do you need to do it in another way?

Comment: I think I found how to add them in my enviroment variables, but I can't seem to find the .dll's

Comment: @StanFieuws I believe, you have to add the directory with libs to, as I remember, **PATH** on _Windows_ and **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** (or **LIBRARY_PATH**) on _Linux/Ubuntu_. Also, the `.exe` should be linked against these libraries but I expect that it is done by the `netbeans` during the compilation

Comment: @StanFieuws also, I guess the libs are in the `netbeans` folder